# Rewrite $\int_{\mathbb{R^4}}\int_{\mathbb{R^4}}\ h(|x|^2,|y|^2,x\cdot y)\ dx\ dy$ as $\int\int\limits_{\Omega}\int\ J(u,v,w)\ h(u,v,w)\ du\ dv\ dw$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> **Question:** Let $h$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $\mathbb{R^3}$.  Rewrite $$\int_{\mathbb{R^4}}\int_{\mathbb{R^4}}\ h\left(|x|^2,|y|^2,x\cdot y\right)\ dx\ dy$$ as $$\iiint_{\Omega} \ J(u,v,w)\ h(u,v,w)\ du\ dv\ dw$$ where $\Omega$ is an appropriate domain in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $J(u,v,w)$ is an appropriate function on $\Omega$.

**My Thoughts:** I'm assuming that this has to deal with Fubini/Tonelli theorems. I suppose I am just unsure on how to deal with $h$, and then how to construct $J$ from that $h$.  I know that the area of the unit $k$-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R^{k+1}}$ is $w_k$, where $w_1=2\pi$, $w_2=4\pi$, and $w_3=2\pi^2$.  So, am I suppose to be taking a $3$-dimensional unit sphere in $\mathbb{R^4}$, and then trying to rewrite $h$ on that sphere, and use the measure of that sphere to come up with our $\Omega$?  Any thoughts, ideas, etc. are very much appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: *Hint*: Cauchy-Schwarz should give you a hint about what $\Omega$ is.  You also need to deal with the 5-dimensional level-sets of $(\lvert x\rvert^2, \lvert y\rvert^2, x\cdot y)$, see [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula).

Comment: @user10354138 I suppose after toying with it for awhile, I am just not quite sure how to do that.... could you help get me started?